# Cannot open project structure anymore in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I cannot open project structure in Android studio any more. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and file -> project structure both are not working. When I try either of these, nothing happens!

I am on Windows 8.1 and have tried deleting the `.AndroidStudio` folder from the Users folder. It resets everything but it didn't help.

I also tried File Invalidate/Restart -> didn't work :-(

Uninstalling and Reinstalling didn't work either. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me couple of months back, and I solved it by reinstalling my Android studio and sdk. If you still have the AS IDE in your Download folders, try to reinstall it. I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

try sync project with gradle.
file -> Sync Project with Gradle Files